# Difference between first condition clauses

Tags: word-choice

Use COULD for possibilities in the future

I am confused is there any difference between the following sentences?

- If it rains on the date of the wedding, we **could** have the ceremony inside the church instead of in the park.
- If it rains on the date of the wedding, we **would** have the ceremony inside the church instead of in the park.
- If it rains on the date of the wedding, we **will** have the ceremony inside the church instead of in the park.

Use WOULD to talk about unreal or unlikely situations. Does the 'would' in the second sentence indicate this meaning?

Answer (score 0):

> If it rains on the date of the wedding, we will have the ceremony inside the church instead of in the park.

This structure is the correct one. Type 1 conditional refers to a possible condition and its probable result. These sentences are based on facts, and they are used to make statements about the real world, and about particular situations.

In type 1 conditional sentences, 
the tense in the 'if' clause is **the simple present**, and the tense in the main clause is **the simple future.**

Also, in type 1 conditional sentences we can use modal verbs in the main clause instead of the future tense. In this sentence to give the meaning of possibility it's better to use **might** instead of could.

> If it rains on the date of the wedding, we might have the ceremony inside the church instead of in the park.

Answer (score 0):

Yes

1. If the situation happens, you can do that, but that's just one of the many possibilities in mind, and depending on how you say it, may even be the undesired choice you mention just for the sake of completeness
2. If the situation happens, that's the choice you will take, but it is implied other alternatives may be taken after you assess the situation
3. if the situation happens, this is the standard procedure, though doesn't discount any changes in the plan

Essentially, it is an escalating level of willingness to go with the plan